# NSFilemanager copyItemsAtPath Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsfilemanager, cordova-plugins

I am creating a iOS Cordova plugin for copying the database file from Resource directory to App documents directory. However, I am getting an error on the copysuccess line and not able to understand it -

```
NSError *err = nil;
copySuccess = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:dbPathFromApp toPath:dbPath error:&err];
```

The log show this -

```
Apr 11 15:07:13 Rahuls-iPhone testapp[506] <Warning>: [sqlDB] Dbname = test.db
Apr 11 15:07:13 Rahuls-iPhone testapp[506] <Warning>: [sqlDB] copying db file
Apr 11 15:07:13 Rahuls-iPhone testapp[506] <Warning>: [sqlDB] Source: /var/mobile/Applications/B1E8723C-9F09-4A2B-B4E3-1FB0A79AB759/testapp.app/test.db
Apr 11 15:07:13 Rahuls-iPhone testapp[506] <Warning>: [sqlDB] Destinatiion: /var/mobile/Applications/B1E8723C-9F09-4A2B-B4E3-1FB0A79AB759/Documents/test.db
Apr 11 15:07:13 Rahuls-iPhone testapp[506] <Warning>: *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument
```

I have tried passing nil to error and also setting the -fno-objc-arc compiler flag, but it doesn't work. Always the same error.

Comment: Could you print the NSError code.

Comment: I didn't get anything else. I pasted the complete log of the app.

Comment: ... which won't contain the NSError code unless you print the NSErrorCode out in your code (using NSLog), as user2071152 is suggesting.

Comment: I uploaded the plugin on github - [https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy](https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy)